# How to write to db with room framework

Tags: android, kotlin, types, orm, android-room

How to write to data base such structure with room?

```
{
    "Status": 200,
    "Result": {
        "10": {
            "name": "test1",
            "surname": "test2"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "tets",
            "surname": "test2"
        }
    }
}
```

but I need create an object from structure as:

```
val int id; //example 10
val name;
val surname;
```

Comment: `@Entity` creation isn't that hard, how are you parsing / handling this json?

Comment: Yes, I have problem with creating TypeConverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON structure cannot be directly translated to Room, as Room doesn't support dynamic keys. Instead, represent data with a "User" entity in Room and an "ApiResponse" data class. Like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(@PrimaryKey val id: Int, val name: String, val surname: String)

data class ApiResponse(val Status: Int, val Result: Map<String, User>)
```

Setup your DAO and Room DB:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user") fun getAll(): List<User>
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) fun insertAll(users: List<User>)
}

@Database(entities = [User::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
}
```

After receiving your JSON response, parse it into ApiResponse, convert Result into a list of User objects, and save them:

```
val apiResponse = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ApiResponse::class.java)
val users = apiResponse.Result.values.toList()
AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).userDao().insertAll(users)
```

Your JSON must include "id" in each user object. Adjust your JSON or parsing logic as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 data class ResultValue(
val name: String,
val surname: String)

data class ResultListEntity(
val Result: Map<String, ResultValue>,
val Status: String
)

val resultListEntity: ResultListEntity = Gson().fromJson(apiResponse, ResultListEntity::class.java)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).